# "Required if" still want to stop SitecoreForms validation if field is hide/display:none in 9.0

Tags: sitecore-forms

I want if the field is `visible/display: block` then only validation works else if the field is `hide/display:none` then validation should stop working.

I hide/show fields with jquery on any click and `onchange` events.

Any solution?

Comment: what have you tried?

Comment: @Richard Seal - I don't know how we can achieve this coz if we check required/Mandatory in the field then the validation appears but I want when my field is not visible then validation did not come after a click on the Next/Submit button.